# redirecting some parts of a url

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting

ok let me try once again this link
 [**www.mgdezigns.com/cards/festive_silver_purple_ornament_holiday_cards_postcard-239887577090743570.html**]
needs to be redirected to this
[**www.zazzle.com/festive_silver_purple_ornament_holiday_cards_postcard-239887577090743570**]  OR [**www.zazzle.com/239887577090743570**] (both links are same and work, whichever is simpler to code)
because what I have pinned to pinterest is this
 
[**www.mgdezigns.com/cards/festive_silver_purple_ornament_holiday_cards_postcard-239887577090743570.html**]
and it shows empty page so what i want is that the people who click on this link 
[**www.mgdezigns.com/cards/festive_silver_purple_ornament_holiday_cards_postcard-239887577090743570.html**]
from pinned images at pinterest.com actually get redirected to 
[**www.zazzle.com/festive_silver_purple_ornament_holiday_cards_postcard-239887577090743570** ] OR [**www.zazzle.com/239887577090743570**] (both links are same and work, whichever is simpler to code)
 is something like this possible?
 Thank You so much!
You will be a life saver!

Comment: How predictable are these URLs? Is the image id (lack of a better term) always the same number of digits? Does the URL always have _card-? Are they always within the cards directory? Any or all is okay. As long as you have one way to determine the pattern.

Comment: no the number of digits will be changing, each product has different number,  i will have to apply the same rule for all my categories, like one for /invitations/ one for /weddings/ i thought if I could figure out one, I could do others, for instance this www.mgdezigns.com/invitations/coral_sunflowers_tea_party_bridal_shower_invites-256702155011593610.html to this www.zazzle.com/256702155011593610 I am somehow having a panicky feeling that this is impossible :(

Comment: Are you in control of `example.com`, or is `example.com` an external URL?

Comment: i am in control of example.com and hence want to edit .htaccess to create some redirect rule, if possible

Comment: Can you edit the question and put in all the /cards/, /invitations/, etc? We can come up with code for you with just that. It may not be a one-liner, but as simple as we can.

Comment: ok added now :)

Comment: Check the help document for [formatting your posts using Markdown](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: I did format it now, i think it is easier to understand now, can you refresh and check my original question now?  I really really really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following in .htaccess to match all the "cards", grabing just the *number* from the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cards/[a-z_]+-([\d]{10,})\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To add more categories you could be explicit...

```
RewriteRule ^(?:cards|invitations|weddings)/[a-z_]+-([\d]{10,})\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or, be generic, to match anything in the first path segment:

```
RewriteRule ^[a-z]+/[a-z_]+-([\d]{10,})\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In fact, you could just match any URL that ends in a hyphen followed by a long number...?

```
RewriteRule -([\d]{10,})\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: and it will not remove the number with each product? just replace www.example.com/cards/by "www.zazzle.com/ " I can try

Comment: It extracts just the number (which must be at least 10 digits).

Comment: tried! but when I go to www.mgdezigns.com/cards/rustic_ribbon_banner_st_patricks_day_card-137070669298455248.html it converts to www.mgdezigns.com/cards/rustic_ribbon_banner_st_patricks_day_card-137070669298455248?title=rustic_ribbon_banner_st_patricks_day_card&pid=137070669298455248 whereas this link remains same, does not get redirected?www.mgdezigns.com/cards/realistic_clovers_pocket_st_patricks_day_card-137618453114920045.html    :/

Comment: i think it is the link , it is showing complete link, removed the h t t p and now working

Comment: Can you wrap URLs in backticks so they don't get parsed... The redirects I posted are external redirects to another domain, so they can't possibly redirect back to `mgdezigns.com`?

Comment: ok let me try once again

Comment: Do these URLs have a query string?

Comment: I edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: You've kinda mashed your question a tad? But your examples are quite different to your initial question, you initially only wanted the _number_, but you want the _full filename_, less the extension now?

Comment: i realized that even the full name did not change earlier i thought it was only numbers that remained same, both will do, either just the numbers or the whole name , less the extension, whatever is simpler to code, i formatted question so you can better compare between two links

Comment: I've updated the regex, try the last one: `RewriteRule -([\d]{10,})\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1 [R=301,L]` to grab just the numbers.

Comment: In what way "not working"? What is `www.pinterest.com/pin/271482683762535017/`?

Comment: tried the regex and the redirect is still not working

Comment: I've just tried all 4 of the examples in my answer (on my own server) and they all work as intended. The short "number only URL" actually redirects to the full URL with description - but that is OK. I was going to suggest clearing your cache (301 redirects are cached, so it is best to test with 302 redirects), but your live example does not work for me either - no redirect occurs at all, which suggests there is "something else" that is conflicting with this. Post your entire `.htaccess` in your question. The .htaccess file is in the document root and mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!1 IT IS WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!! cache clear solve dthe problem!!!!!!!!!1 wow you are AWESOME!!!!!!!!!!! cannot thank you enough!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the `.html` on URLs that otherwise would end in a number, you could use this:

```
 RedirectMatch permanent /(.*[0-9])\.html$ /$1
```

Older versions of Apache (before 2.2.6) don't support relative URLs and you would have to use the full URL:

```
 RedirectMatch permanent /(.*[0-9])\.html$ http://www.zazzle.com/$1
```

Comment: trying this too! *fingers crossed*